# How to omit the xml declarations when using XElement.Save?

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader, xelement

`XElement.Save` actually does what I need but it starts the file with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Should I save using other types, methods after I finish creating my `XElement`?

Or should I be skipping that line via `XmlReader.Read`? Because doing this I feel like it's more fragile as I am assuming the first line is always gonna be this xml declaration.

What's the simpliest way to accomplish this?

Comment: why do you want to leave that out?

Comment: Thanks John, now I don't need to I think because your way of reading the xml worked. Otherwise I was getting an error with my method posted in the other question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`XElement.ToString()` won't add the XML declaration to the output. But I don't understand why `XmlReader` - or any XML parser - would have trouble with a standard XML declaration.

Comment: Thanks, when I used the reader it throws an exception saying, invalid data root, line 1, etc.

Comment: I've seen a very similar error caused by the Byte Order Mark at the beginning of the file. Might be worth investigating.

Answer (score 6):

This example writes the example ***xmlTree*** data to text file ***data.xml*** without a declaration line, yet includes indentation formatting:

```
XElement xmlTree = new XElement("Root",
  new XAttribute("Attribute1", 1),
  new XElement("Child1", 1),
  new XElement("Child2", 2)
);
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("data.xml", new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true }))
  xmlTree.Save(writer);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using an XmlWriter will give you this ability.

Microsoft article: [Serializing with an XML Declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387027.aspx) describes how to control whether serialization generates an XML declaration.